# Update multiple Json with CURL POST

Tags: bash, api, shell, curl, post

I would like to update multiple JSON filed in the same curl POST but I am not able to make it work.

I keep getting 400.

I tried checking online but was not able to find another way. Maybe there is an easier way of doing this but I am not sure what it is. Thanks for the help

I tried the following

```
   curl -X 'PUT' \
  'http://192.168.1.256:123/api/accessories/123456789' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer $token' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "characteristicType": "Saturation",
  "value": "30"
}
{
  "characteristicType": "On",
  "value": "1"
}'
```

```
   curl -X 'PUT' \
  'http://192.168.1.256:123/api/accessories/123456789' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer $token' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "characteristicType": "Saturation",
  "value": "30"
},
{
  "characteristicType": "On",
  "value": "1"
}'
```

```
  curl -X 'PUT' \
  'http://192.168.1.256:123/api/accessories/123456789' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer $token' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '[
{
  "characteristicType": "Saturation",
  "value": "30"
}
{
  "characteristicType": "On",
  "value": "1"
}
]'
```

Comment: This is quite dependent on the server side code. What's in there? Did you try `{ { <attributes1> }, { <attributes2> } }`? Why exactly do you want to send multiple payloads in the same request?

Comment: This will turn on a light and change the saturation. I guess I can try multiple curl calls

Answer (score 0):

You may test what comes to the server by using a dummy `nc` server in localhost with an arbitrary port such as in the example below:

```
$ nc -l 10000
```

And change this IP/port in the `curl` command, so the first example becomes:

```
curl -X 'PUT' \
  'localhost:10000' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer $token' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "characteristicType": "Saturation",
  "value": "30"
}
{
  "characteristicType": "On",
  "value": "1"
}'
```

This is what the server will received:

```
$ nc -l 10000
PUT / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:10000
User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer $token
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 106

{
  "characteristicType": "Saturation",
  "value": "30"
}
{
  "characteristicType": "On",
  "value": "1"
}
```

How the server will parse this is implementation dependent.
In `curl` man page, it suggests using an ampersand (`&`) to add multiple data payloads. This can be done by the command itself by adding `-d` parameter multiple times:

```
curl -X 'PUT' \
  'localhost:10000' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer $token' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "characteristicType": "Saturation",
  "value": "30"
  }' \
  -d '{
  "characteristicType": "On",
  "value": "1"
}'
```

Very certainly your server will not like the resulting syntax in the body though considering it's json.

As an additional note, be careful with using bash variables inside quoted strings. If they are single quoted instead of double quoted, they are not expanded. You probably should use `-H "Authorization: Bearer $token"` instead.